# Create regex that matches at least one non letter character or end of string

Tags: regex

I am looking for regex to match following set:

```
/VIDEO_PRE_MINE
/VIDEO_PRE
/VIDEO_PRE/
/VIDEO_PRE/SOMETHING
```

And I want exclude expresions like this:

```
/VIDEO_PRESOMETHING
/VIDEO_PREsomething/something
```

In other words after expression '_PRE' cannot be any literal character, but it can be end of the string.

Here are regexes that i tried: 

`1.  ^\/[^\/]*_PRE[^a-z|A-Z]
2.  ^\/[^\/]*_PRE[^a-z|A-Z]?$`

However I didn't manage to cover all use cases from sets with those regex.

I would really appreciate any help with this. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^\/[^\/]*_PRE(?:[_/].*)?$` https://regex101.com/r/N8InoU/1

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for quick response. If you add your answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data, you could add an optional group `(?:[_/].*)?` to match either a `_` or `/` followed by matching any char except a newline 0+ times until the end of the string `$`

```
^/[^/]*_PRE(?:[_/].*)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `/[^/]*` Match `/`, then 0+ times any char except `/`
- `_PRE` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[_/].*` Match either _ or / followed by 0+ times any char except a newline
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mwqoa6/1)

Note that the forward slashes are not escaped. Depending on the language or delimiters you might have to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that we might want to have some right boundaries, such as

```
^\/VIDEO_PRE(?:\b\/?|\/[^\/\s]+\/?|_[^\/\s]+\/?)$
```

in specified form, and in general form:

```
^\/[^_]+_PRE(?:\b\/?|\/[^\/\s]+\/?|_[^\/\s]+\/?)$
```

which might work. You would likely want to test and modify the expression, which is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6UBy4I/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/6UBy4I/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/55AnHH/1/)